# AngularJS include a file located in a folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I do

*/sites/all/themes/theme/js/controller.js*

```
$scope.template = 'partials/tpl.html'
```

*/sites/all/themes/theme/js/index.html*

```
<div ng-include='template'></div>
```

*/sites/all/themes/theme/js/partials/tpl.html*

```
<b>Ho boy!</b>
```

*I basically moved everything related to angular into js folder.*

It returns `localhost/partials/tpl.html` while I need `localhost/sites/all/themes/js/partials/tpl.html`. How do I solve that without using an absolute path?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle/plnkr? I have similar implementation working.

Comment: how can I include a file from an other folder in jsfiddle or plnkr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue using $httpProvider.interceptors. The following prepends 'myAppDirectory' to ALL requests.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
     'request': function(config) {
         config.url = 'myAppDirectory/'+config.url;
         return config;
      },
    };
  });
```

A regular ng-include, such as:

```
<div ng-include="'user/info.html'">
```

Will load **myAppDirectory/user/info.html**

You probably want to make some exceptions. In my case:

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
     'request': function(config) {
         // ignore api calls and ui-bootstrap templates.
         if (config.url.indexOf('api')==-1 && config.url.indexOf('template')==-1) {
           config.url = 'myAppDirectory/'+config.url;
         }
         return config;
      },
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<base href="/sites/all/themes/theme/js/">` at the top of your `<head>` element inside `index.html`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/sites/all/themes/theme/js/">
    ...
```

[Reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

> Relative links
>
> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. You must
>   either specify the url base in the head of your main html file (<base
>   href="/my-base">) or you must use absolute urls (starting with /)
>   everywhere because relative urls will be resolved to absolute urls
>   using the initial absolute url of the document, which is often
>   different from the root of the application.
>
> Running Angular apps with the History API enabled from document root
>   is strongly encouraged as it takes care of all relative link issues.

Comment: Could work, but it'll break all my routes, I'm using drupal as backend

Comment: @JonathandeM. Then try to include `$location` in your controller and use `$scope.template = $location.path() + '/partials/tpl.html'`